# If there is a function $g:B \rightarrow A$ s.t. g(f(x))=x $\forall x\in A$ then f is injective

Tags: functions

If there is a function $g:B \rightarrow A$ s.t. $\forall x\in A$, g(f(x))=x then f is injective.

Assume f isn't injective. Then we can see that for each g(f(x)) to equal x for every x then g must output every x given some input, but it also says that g(f(x))=x so that means for every x that f(x) must output a unique value y s.t. g(y)=x otherwise if it didn’t then g(f(x)) wouldn’t equal x so therefore we have a contradiction.

I don't feel my proof is sufficient. Any input would be good.

Comment: You might benefit by watching this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E0-WOYEvTmQ&t=1s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea might be correct, but the formulation is confusing and not exact. An indirect proof would go like this:

Assume that $f$ is not injective. Then there are $x_1, x_2 \in A$ with $x_1 \ne x_2$ and $f(x_1) = f(x_2)$. But then $x_1 = g(f(x_1)) = g(f(x_2)) = x_2$ and we have a contradiction.

But a *direct* proof is even simpler: $f$ is injective if for all $x_1, x_2 \in A$, $f(x_1) = f(x_2)$ implies $x_1 = x_2$. And that holds because
$$
 f(x_1) = f(x_2) \implies \underbrace{g(f(x_1))}_{= x_1} = \underbrace{g(f(x_2))}_{= x_2} \implies
 x_1  = x_2 \, .
$$